# Angular 5 pass Module as Component in router

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am creating an angular 5 application where i wanted to separate the login module with the rest of the application. Have created two separate modules, **login.module.ts** and **home.module.ts**

**login.module.ts** is

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

**home.module.ts** is

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

And finally, my app.module.ts is

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginModule },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeModule },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LoginModule,
    HomeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Although after running the application, i am getting the following error in browser console:

> core.js:1440 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for LoginModule. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
>   Error: No component factory found for LoginModule. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Can someone help me to resolve this issue, or tell what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can't you use lazy loading for modules? That way you can load what you want after you are logged in, by protecting your lazy routes with a guard

Comment: Ya right. Can you help me for achieving the same ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Modules are used to declare components, while components are used to display a view to your user. You should route components, not modules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, this will work but it will not satisfy the requirement, as i have to provide everything(import everythng) in my app.module.ts. Everythng will be loaded when app gets initialized. I wanted only the login related things to be loaded for login and rest to be loaded after successfull login.

Comment: What. I don't even know what you are talking about. Anyway, you can't make Angular do what you want, you have to do what Angular wants. And the reality is that you can't provide a module to a route? That's the way it is.

Comment: Well in simple terms, i was talking about "lazy loading". I don't want all the components to be loaded before login. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That isn't how it works at all ! Didn't you look at the documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
//app.module.ts
import {CanLoad, Route, RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
//...
@Injectable()
//You should implement CanActivate as well
class CanLoadAuthenticatedRoute implements CanLoad
{
    constructor()
    {
    }

    canLoad(route: Route): boolean
    {
      //check here is user is logged in
      return false;
    }
}

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
     { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './home.module#HomeModule', canLoad: [CanLoad]},
//other lazy loaded routes
];
```